# (Swift) NSTimer Stop when Scrolling

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, nstimer

Help me.
I tried to make NSTimer with UIScrollView. but 
NSTimer stop during Scrolling on UIScroll View..

How can I keep work NSTimer during scrolling?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I created a simple project with a scrollView and a label that is updated with an `NSTimer`.  When creating the timer with `scheduledTimerWithInterval`, the timer does not run when scrolling.

The solution is to create the timer with `NSTimer:timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats` and then call `addTimer` on `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop()` with `mode` `NSRunLoopCommonModes`.  This allows the timer to update while scrolling.

Here it is running:

[image: Demo .gif]

Here is my demo code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    var count = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        timerLabel.text = "0"

        // This doesn't work when scrolling
        // let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        // Do these two lines instead:
        let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }

    func update() {
        count += 1
        timerLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
}
```

## Swift 3:

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

## Swift 4, 5:

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
```

Comment: i used this code-> //  pushButtonCountTimer  = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:
            ("pushButtonThreeMinuete"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            pushButtonCountRunning = true    // i change that code like your code like this ->   pushButtonCountTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "pushButtonThreeMinuete", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  // but not working timer.. i am a starter about programming...it is very hard.. ;( any way thanks very much mr.Vacawama

Comment: You need to also do after that:  `if let timer = pushButtonCountTimer { NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes) }` so that the timer runs.

Comment: i entered that code but.. i can see red error message-> initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSTimer' .. what is this message.. ;->

Comment: Sorry about that.  In my code I had declared `timer` as an optional `NSTimer?`, but you didn't.  So, ignore the `if let` part and just do `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(pushButtonCountTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)`