# Timer Does Not Update In CollectionView Properly Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a timer in a collection view in a timer, and it ticks down, but every time I swipe, in the middle of the swipe the timer just stops[image]

As you see in the picture the timer is still when you swipe,it only starts ticking when you are done with the swipe. Here is the code:

`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(QuestionsViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)`

```
func update() {
    if counter >= 0 {
        self.title = "Time Left: \(String(self.counter))"
        counter -= 1
    } else {
        alert()
        timer!.invalidate()
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34234939/1630618

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a UITableView on a timer while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303189/how-do-i-update-a-uitableview-on-a-timer-while-scrolling)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the timer to the main run loop:

`RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)`